# Android spinner, OnItemSelectedListener is not called when selecting the same item?

Tags: android, spinner

For a particular reason I need my `spinner`'s `OnItemSelectedListener` gets called even when user chooses the same item, but normally it doesn't. So I don't know how it is possible!
Any trick or libraries that can solve my problem?

Comment: you can use `OnItemClickListener` event instead `OnItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Sounds like `OnItemClickListener` is not intended to be used with Android's `Spinner`, because when I do it, the app crashes. @Farrokh

Comment: do u have more than a spinner ???

Comment: Yeah, I've got other widgets too. But I don't think it's a matter of their presence. Look, there is no issue to get solved. It's a problem that needs a solution. @hamidkeyhani

Comment: i'm so sorry for my wrong answer, but you can try my new answer posted below

Comment: i hope i can help to u . but first i should see image of your design and spinner items . plz put a image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok
you can use `addOnLayoutChangeListener`

```
yourspinner.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "item is : " + yourspinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't help honestly. But it gave me the idea to get the `Spinner` popup view somehow then `popup.addOnLayoutChangeListener`! But how to get `Spinner` popup? @Farrokh

Comment: i tried this code and do what you need, every time spinner layout changes, a toast appear on screen, it include selecting new item or clicking same item, what do you need exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right! It is exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure about the context. you can context as.

- this
- MainActivity.this
- getApplicationContext()

If you are using the spinner in **Fragment** then you can use context as

> getActivity()

```
String selectedItem;
String data[]={"Australia","Delhi","Agra","Mumbai","America","Tanzania","Arizona"};
spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,data);
       spinner.setPrompt("Select State");
       spinner.setAdapter(ad);
    String val=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               String val=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

               selectedItem=data[i];

                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " "+selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

           }
       });
```